# How to assign content their own height using grid?

Tags: css, grid

[https://codepen.io/daniel-brown/pen/QWjXpXw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88R4.jpg)

I need this li, to have their own height and not someone else’s

[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88R4.jpg)

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div>


  <li>industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
  <li>Lorem ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </li>
  <li> unknown </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of thver since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
  <li>L printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettinry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
  <li> when an unknown </li>
  <li>Lorem </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Please better describe what you're trying to get. What is "their own height" vs "someone else's" in your example?

Comment: you should try something first

Answer (score 0):

I can't change it, I have this ul li structure and I have to sort it through the grid

- text
- text
- text
- text
- text
- text

Answer (score -1):

To do that use the css inline property to add height to the li element individually

```
<li style="height:10px;"> text </li>
```

But i would rather suggest using the bootstrap grid system, and then assign the height parameter using inline styling :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
  <ul>
  <li style="height:10px;"> text </li>
  <li> text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  <ul>
  <li> text </li>
  <li> text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  <ul>
  <li> text </li>
  <li> text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```